# Spring cloud gateway second path does not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I have an application in which I want to hide my auth server and my base api behind a gateway. Creating route to one or the other works just fine, but if I try to create two routes the second one does not work and I get error 404. This behavior is seen no matter which route is first and which is second. Rewriting it as a Bean in Java has the same effect.

Here is my actual configuration:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway-service
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        #  Authentication server
        - id: auth-server
          uri: lb://auth-server
          predicates:
            - Path=/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/auth(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}
        #  Base API
        - id: base-api
          uri: lb://sharedtravel-api
          predicates:
            - Path=/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/api(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}
```

Comment: The two predicates are the same. There second one will never match. You have to differentiate between them. Either by path or host or header or something

Comment: You have it in your rewrite filter. Change the paths to /auth/** and /api/**

Comment: @spencergibb could you make a comment in order for me to accept it as this solved my issue?

Answer (score 0):

Both the routes having same predicate path, while request delegation spring cloud gate way first looks at predicate path do the further steps. Change the predicate path.